# How to use function parameters with jQuery onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function slide(var) {

     if ( parseInt( var.css('marginLeft') ) >= -2160 ){

        var.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
        });

      }

}

onclick='(document.getElementById('slides'))'
```

How can I make this function work by replacing the function parameter (var) with the div slides id?

Comment: `onclick` is not a jQuery thing.  Also `var` is a special word in javascript.  While this is not a syntax error, it could very easily lead to a logical error.

Comment: You are also not invoking the slide method in your onclick, but even if you were, `var` is a DOM Element ( document.getElementById('slides') ), not a jQuery object.  You will need to wrap it in `$()` if you want to use the `animate()` method which is a jQuery method.  Same issue is present for the `css()` method.

Comment: `onclick='slide(document.getElementById(\'slides\'))'`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to bind the handler. Inside the jQuery handler, `this` is the target element.

```
$("#slides").click(function() {
    slide($(this));
}
```